# Data Science Take Home Challenge Interpretation of Question

Tags: classification, binary-data

I am currently applying for a Data Science position and have to finish a take-home challenge for one of the companies. However, I don't really understand what they want me to do and hope you can help me interpret the question. Unfortunately, I can't reach anyone at the company due to Christmas holidays

I have a data set with transactions of customers and another dataset with information about age, country... of those customers. Now I am asked to define a target metric for engagement and say how I would define unengaged vs. engaged customer. Afterwards, I have to use this logic to build a model to classify engaged vs unengaged customers (they point out overfitting due to feature used in the target metric).

How would you interpret these questions?

Do I first have to say *if target_metric > x: engaged* and then build a supervised model to classify the users again?

OR

Would you define several metrics that could separate engaged and unengaged customers and then use an unsupervised model to find two clusters that would then be engaged vs unengaged?

I tried to keep the question as general as possible to avoid "cheating". I only want to know how you would interpret them. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it's up to you. If you use several metrics, then your 'actual' metric is some weighted average of them all. Side note, you might want to edit out the 'more experienced Redditor' in p1.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion! I think I will simply explain how I interpret the question and why this interpretation makes sense from a business point. (And thanks for spotting the Reddit thing)

Comment: As written, this doesn't sound like a statistical problem: the question comes down to what the company might mean by "engagement," which is an issue of what the business values and measures.  What information did they supply about this?  Did they give a definition (unlikely) or at least a clear characterization?

Comment: +1 @whuber's comment. A "data scientist" needs to be able to propose relevant metrics as well as how to best model them. *Personal anecdote*: In a similar challenge years ago (~2016), I used ordinal regression so I can account for multiple incremental categorisations. The recruiter told me that while the DS team reviewer did not think it was wrong it was deemed I would not be a good fit for the team. (So much for make a point of classification vs. ranking...)

Comment: @whuber They did not provide any form of definition. It is my task to come up with a definition. It is in the finance sector which is why I decided to use things like total transaction amount and number of transactions to characterise engagement.